# What is the different between Auto Loan and Car Mortgage?

Tags: mortgage, auto-loan, sri-lanka

I'm trying to get loan from the bank and I'm going for a special interest rate category called Professional loan scheme. Since my qualification time period is low and got the degree recently they're asking me to mortgage the car. Are there any differences between car mortgage and auto loan? Is it ok to say "yes" to go for the car mortgage ?

Comment: Can you edit and add country tag

Comment: And state if it's in the US - state laws differ on auto loans as well.

Comment: Really, there is no such thing as a "mortgage" on a car.  Someone is using a term strangely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frankly it is just weird terminology in today's jargon.  While Webster defines a mortgage as:

> a conveyance of or lien against property (as for securing a loan) that becomes void upon payment or performance according to stipulated terms.

Almost all traditional car loans are secured by the car being purchased, so technically they would qualify as a mortgage per Webster, however they are rarely called that. Given some of the reading I did on the matter, I would speculate that this lending institution could call it a "car mortgage" if the loan extends for a long time.

Another point of speculation is that they may call it that to make it sound more sophisticated.  In other words it might be just a marketing ploy.

Can you link the institution that is providing this loan?

Comment: OP's profile indicates Sri Lanka as their location. I'm curious if there's a separate product there for this (I couldn't find anything via Google), or if there's a translation issue that might be at play. I'd agree with the marketing ploy theory if neither of those are the case.

Comment: My reading was that the OP already owns the car. They now want to take out a loan (for some unrelated purpose) and the bank are asking them to "mortgage" the car (i.e. put it up as collateral for the loan).

Comment: Indeed, i googled "Sri Lanka Car Mortgage" and it's not a thing.  Some minimum wage bank officer (or, whatever) just got terms mixed-up.

Comment: This could easily be a variant of what is called a [title loan](https://www.titlemax.com/title-loans/) in the U.S.  The terminology does not match U.S. terminology, but the concept certainly exists.